# ¿Porque el hosting 000.webhost no guarda los registros a la Base de datos?

Tags: php

Estoy subiendo varios archivo PHP en el servidor 000.webhost para mi aplicación android pero en algunos archivos si me inserta los datos correctamente, pero en el otros archivos que tienen la misma sintaxis y si me guarda los datos y algunos me sale datos no insertados, lo raro es que de manera local ahí no tengo ningún problema todos los archivos PHP funcionan ya que son los mismos mismos archivos así como la base de datos que están en el servidor remoto, alguien sabe aque se debe esto.

**registroMedicamento.php que tengo en servidor remoto**

```
<?php

   include('conexion.php');

   $codigo = $_POST["codigoMedica"];
   $descriProdu = $_POST["descriProducto"];
   $cantidad = $_POST["cantidadProduc"];
   $unidadMedi = $_POST["unidadMedida"];
   $tipoPresen = $_POST["tipoPresentacion"];
   $fechaIngre = $_POST["fechaIngreso"];
   $fechaCadu = $_POST["fechaCaducida"];



   $query = "INSERT INTO t_medicamento(codigoMedica,descriProducto,cantidadProduc,
  unidadMedida,tipoPresentacion,fechaIngreso,fechaCaducida)
 VALUES('$codigo','$descriProdu','$cantidad','$unidadMedi','$tipoPresen','$fechaIngre','$fechaCadu')";

     $result = $mysql->query($query);

       if ($result) {
       echo "Datos intsertados";

      } else {
      echo "Datos no insertados";
      }
     $mysql->close();

     ?>
```

**Error**

`` Error description: Incorrect integer value: '' for column `id17223682_logishuman`.`t_medicamento`.`cantidadProduc` at row 1Datos no insertados ``

**Tabla de la BD t_medicamento**
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: y cambiaste los parametros de conexion a la base de datos en el host?

Comment: @gbianchi en la conexión ya están cambiados tal como me los dio el servidor remoto porque tengo otros archivos que si me insertan los datos y tengo la misma sintaxis de sentencia SQL.

Comment: Entonces esa query tiene que estar tirando error.. verifica que no haya un error... asi como esta, no podemos hacer mucho...

Comment: H-j Angel, yo tuve errores muy parecidos, lo que hacia era cambiar los archivos de inserción a la base de datos por archivos que mostraran el error, por ejemplo con un (en tu caso) *echo $mysql->error()* y asi ya desde la pagina podía ver el error, intenta hacer eso

Comment: @Davidflogar gracias por el dato lo voy verificar.

Comment: @gbianchi despues de hacer lo siguiente `echo("Error description: " . $mysql -> error);` tal como dijo David flogar, me salio el error, ya edite mi pregunta.

Comment: Entonces ese dato no te esta llegnado.. lo comprobaste?

Comment: @gbianchi lleno los datos desde la aplicación y no se insertan a la base de datos me sale no insertados

Comment: de vuelta... comprobaste que a tu back le esten llegando los datos?

Comment: el error es claro.. ese valor no esta llegando...

Comment: Si puedes pon una foto resumida de como recibes los datos y de como los insertas, incluyendo la consulta sql y el valor y columnas de la tabla que falla

Comment: @Davidflogar lo raro es del servidor porque borre ese campo que me daba el error y ahora me salio que el campo  fecha esta mal.

Comment: Has revisado que cuando creaste la base de datos del host la creaste exactamente como la original, y que los valores tanto de la base de datos como los de la inserción son correctos?

Comment: @Davidflogar si ya los revise pero todo esta bien, incluso los subí a otro servidor remoto y ahí no hay problemas, solo que esta restringido ese servidor.

Comment: Ya veo, pues creo en base al error que te devuelve si no me equivoco estas metiendo tipos de datos incorrectos a las columnas